# Annotation identifier in viewForAnnotation

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

I am creating custom annotations and I am trying to use dequeueReusableAnnotation.
The difference between the pins are the png that is used for pin image.

I have created myAnnotation class and I use this code when I am creating the annotation:

```
  if([category isEqualToString:@"anti-social-behaviour"]){
        point.annotationImg=@"A.png";

    }
    else
        if([category isEqualToString:@"burglary"]){
            point.annotationImg=@"B.png";

        }
        else....
```

Now in the viewForAnnotation:

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
     {

if ([annotation class] == MKUserLocation.class) {
    return nil;

 }

static NSString *identifier = @"myPin";

MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;

pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (pinView == nil)
{
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[(Annotation*)annotation annotationImg]];

}


return pinView;
```

}

I know I have to use the identifier somehow but i didn't figure it out.
The issue now is that the first time I load the pins are fine and the second one the images get messed.
Any recommendations?

Comment: Should I use a lot if/else to give each annotation it's category?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend implementing the following line of code outside of if/else block as what is happening when you dequeued the MKPinAnnotationView and if it returns a view, you are just returning the view which is dequeued which still references the old image.

So you need to set the image outside of if/else right after it, it should be something like

```
if (pinView == nil)
{
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
}

pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[(Annotation*)annotation annotationImg]];
```

Comment: I'd also suggest updating the view's annotation property as well as the image.  A separate issue OP may see is the image getting replaced with the default pin because code creates a MKPinAnnotationView instead of plain MKAnnotationView.